# Extract one Feature from Feature Collection

Tags: google-earth-engine

I have a feature collection consisting of three individual features, each of which represents an AOI in an area. Now I want to get each feature separately to load the appropriate Sentinel2 data for it. First of all I load the FIRMS (MODIS) Data and convert day to date. Then I clip the mosaic to my AOI.
This is my code:

```
  var FIRMS_filtered = ee.ImageCollection('FIRMS')
 .filterDate('2018-01-01', '2018-12-31')
 .filterBounds(AOI)
 .select('T21')
 .map(function(image) {
 var date = ee.Date(image.get('system:time_start')).format("YYYY-DDD");
 date = ee.Date(date);
 return image.set('date', date);
 })
.map(function(image) {
var ID = ee.String(image.get('system:index'));
 return image.set('ID', ID);
})
.map(function(image) {
 var date = ee.Date(image.get('system:time_start'));
 return image.set('date_time', date);
 });
```

Then I create a Vector from the result and a Buffer.

```
  //Creation AOI mask for vectorization
  var T21 = FIRMS_filtered.mosaic().clip(AOI).select('T21');
  var zones = T21.gt(0);
  zones = zones.updateMask(zones.neq(0));

  //Creation of vector
  var vectors = zones.addBands(T21).reduceToVectors({
  geometry: AOI,
  crs: T21.projection(),
  scale: 500,
  geometryType: 'polygon',
 eightConnected: false,
 labelProperty: 'zone',
 reducer: ee.Reducer.mean()});

//Function for creating buffer
var buffer = function(feature) {
return feature.buffer(2000);};
//Creation buffer
var bounds_AOI = vectors.map(buffer);
```

The result is a Feature Collection with 3 Features. Now I want to get each of this Features single.
How can I do this?

Here is the code

https://code.earthengine.google.com/def19f2aed544401711895df71be76d7

Answer (score 1):

Not the best answer, and would only work with your code.  This solution is not at all portable.

You can add this to your code at the bottom.

```
var bounds_AOI_West = bounds_AOI.filterMetadata("system:index","equals","+5270+8474").first()

var bounds_AOI_Center = bounds_AOI.filterMetadata("system:index","equals","+5308+8474").first()

var bounds_AOI_East = bounds_AOI.filterMetadata("system:index","equals","+5344+8474").first()
```

Now you have each of the features in their own object.

Comment: Is there a possibility to convert each Feature now into a Geometry? I want to have only the data which are in the extension of the feature

Answer (score 1):

Thank you very much. This helps me a lot. But now I need each Feature as a Polygon because I want to search for Data in the new Polygon. 
I always get an Error for the code like: "ImageCollection (Error)
Feature, argument 'geometry': Invalid type. Expected: Geometry. Actual: Feature."

Here is my Code

```
  var bounds_AOI_West = bounds_AOI.filterMetadata("system:index","equals","+5270+8474").first();
  bounds_AOI_West = bounds_AOI_West.set('geo_type', 'Polygon')

  var GeometryWest = ee.Feature(bounds_AOI_West);

  var FIRMS_West = FIRMS_filtered
  .filterDate('2018-01-01', '2018-12-31')
  .filterBounds(GeometryWest)
  .select('T21')
```

Here is the complete Code link: https://code.earthengine.google.com/8c3d499d59dd499ea496162bcef16965

Comment: Just change your GeometryWest code to add the .geometry() at the end. ///////////
var GeometryWest = ee.Feature(bounds_AOI_West).geometry();